# How to allow a specific group to be Assigned to a list?

Tags: list, permissions, person

When assigning a specific group that the "assign to people or group" can choose. Like in this instance "Gæðadeild members".

[image: Edit column]

When starting to write the name of someone in the group "Gæðadeild members" in the assign field, it does not find anybody.

Is there something that I'm not doing right or need to change?

Comment: Do you become able to select any user if you change the group or if you allow choosing from all users? Have you ensured that there are users in the group "Gæðadeild members" from site permissions?

Comment: If I change to select any user, all users come up. I also tried to change the group to Approvers and added myself to the Approvers group in site permission. My name still does not come up.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a permission issue.

Make sure the group members can be viewed by everyone and not only by group members.